# Java and REST web service - GET method returns JSONObject["....."] is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to get response in JAVA from REST web service.

Using HTTP Request tool JSON structure is returned properly.
This is the JSON response which can be seen in browser's add-on tool:

```
{
    "QueryMXASSETResponse": {
        "rsStart": 0,
        "rsCount": 1,
        "MXASSETSet": {
            "ASSET": [
                {
                    "Attributes": {
                        "ASSETID": {
                            "content": 123
                        },
                        "ASSETNUM": {
                            "content": "SM-A-3002"
                        },
                        "DESCRIPTION": {
                            "content": "restint"
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my code in MAIN method in Java App (I want to get DESCRIPTION value)

```
String response = httpGet("http://192.168.150.18:9080/maxrest/rest/os/mxasset/?assetid=~eq~123");
    System.out.println(response+"\n");             
    //Parsing JSON response
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    if (jsonObj.has("QueryMXASSETResponse")){
        JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("QueryMXASSETResponse");
        JSONObject jsonObj3 = jsonObj2.getJSONObject("MXASSETSet");
        JSONObject jsonObj4 = jsonObj3.getJSONObject("ASSET");
        JSONObject jsonObj5 = jsonObj4.getJSONObject("Attributes");         
        JSONObject jsonObj6= jsonObj5.getJSONObject("DESCRIPTION");
        System.out.println("Description is: "+jsonObj6.getString("content"));

    }
```

Error returned is for the jsonObj4 which says it is not JSONObject although you can see in response above that it is. Why I am gettin exception? Can you please help? Thanks

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ASSET"] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:557)
    at com.getAsset.GETAssets.main(GETAssets.java:91)
```

Comment: ASSET is not a JSONObject, it's a JSONArray

Comment: Hi Daniel... Can you please update my code so I can get desired result?  want to retrieve value from DESCRIPTION field from ASSET object.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example JSON "ASSET" contains a collection. This can be seen by the `"ASSET": [`. You need to use [JSON Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) instead.

**Answer using json.org library**

```
JSONObject descriptionJson = null;
if (jsonObj3.has("ASSET")) {
    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj3.getJSONArray("ASSET");
    if (jsonArray1.length() > 0) {
        JSONObject asset = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject attributesObj = asset.getJSONObject("ATTRIBUTE");
        descriptionJson = attributesObj.getJSONObject("DESCRIPTION");
    }
}
if (descriptionJson != null) {
    //Do your processing here.
}
```

**Answer using Java JSON API**

```
JSONObject descriptionJson = null;
JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObj3.getJSONArray("ASSET");
if (jsonArray1 != null && !jsonArray1.isEmpty()) {
    JSONObject asset = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject attributesObj = asset.getJSONObject("ATTRIBUTE");
    descriptionJson = attributesObj.getJSONObject("DESCRIPTION");
}
if (descriptionJson != null) {
    //Do your processing here.
}
```

This is assuming that nothing can be null but the list may be empty. If this is not true then you can add null-checking or remove the `isEmpty` check.

Comment: Hi. Daniel. And how after that to retrieve value from DESCRIPTION element which is below the ASSET/Attributes part? Thank you

Comment: Hi Daniel. Shouldn't it be NOT EMPTY? Why IS EMPTY?? is this mistake?

Comment: I was going based on the Java EE [JSONArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) which can be treated as a list. If you are using a different JSON framework your methods may be different.

Comment: @Dejan I see what you mean now. You are correct. I have edited my answer to be `!...isEmpty()`

Comment: Hi Daniel. I marked this as answer. But my object or array do not have isEmpty method to be checked. Complile error is presented. Can I check somehow differently if object does exist or it has below objects in it? I am getting cannot find symbol for method isEmpty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147843/discussion-between-daniel-bickler-and-dejan).

Answer (score 1):

Well ... the square brackets in this part of the JSON

```
"ASSET": [ ... ]
```

tells us that `"ASSET"` is a `JSONArray`and not a `JSONObject`.

Parse it as an array or correct the serving side if it should have been an object instead.

If the JSON is fix (and is guaranteed to contain one object in the asset array), then you simply can change your code to

```
JSONObject jsonObj4 = jsonObj3.getJSONArray("ASSET").getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jsonObj5 = jsonObj4.getJSONObject("Attributes");         
JSONObject jsonObj6= jsonObj5.getJSONObject("DESCRIPTION");
```

Comment: I haven't worked with JSON arrays. Can you please update the code so I could retreive value from DESCRIPTION column? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use getJSONArray

```
JSONArray jsonObj4 = json.getJSONArray("ASSET");
```

Comment: Hi. And how after that to retrieve value from DESCRIPTION element? Thank you